# While using XMLEventReader to read part of an XML file, how to configure the enclosing tag of the result?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have this XML file:

```
<items>
    <item><name>nam1</name><price>30</price></item>
    <item><name>nam2</name><price>30</price></item>
</items>
```

I'm interested in reading the first `item` element as an XML [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), using [`XMLEventReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html). I have this code:

```
  try (var reader = new FileReader("items.xml", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        final XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        final XMLEventReader xer = xif.createXMLEventReader(reader);
        final TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        final Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        // Skip until just *after* the first opening <item> tag
        for (XMLEvent event = xer.peek()
             ; !event.isStartElement() ||
               !event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals("item")
             ; event = xer.nextEvent()) {
        }
        final DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
        t.transform(new StAXSource(xer), result);
        final Node node = result.getNode();
    }
```

In the code, I position the "cursor" just after the first `<item>` tag, then read the whole element.

It seems to work, except that when I pretty-print the resulting `Node`, the name of the first tag encountered during parsing (`name`) seems to be used for the tag name of the enclosing element as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<name>
  <name>nam1</name>
  <price>30</price>
</name>
```

I expected the name of the closing tag (`item`) to be used. Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<item>
  <name>nam1</name>
  <price>30</price>
</item>
```

Is there a way to get this second behavior, or to otherwise configure the tag name of the enclosing element?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a new [`Element`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) with the desired tag and copy into it all the children of the parse result:

```
final DocumentBuilder builder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document newDocument = builder.newDocument();
final Document document = (Document) result.getNode();
final Element element = (Element) document.getFirstChild();
final DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final Element newElement = newDocument.createElement("item");
final NodeList childNodes = element.getChildNodes();
for (int i=0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    newElement.appendChild(newDocument.importNode(childNodes.item(i),true));
}
```

But it feels somewhat roundabout and inelegant.